# Remove Arrafinity Cookie from API requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, cookies

Context: I am working on a web form application hosted using an Azure App service. The WebForm application is hosted together with a WebApp project
    I would want that API requests from Angular no longer pass the Arrafinity cookie ( which is HttpOnly), or that the the cookie is ignored by just the API.
How could I achieve this ? ( The API is stateless, the Web Form is not )

Answer (score 2):

ARR Affinity can be disabled on the Web App Configuration General Settings tab. See [this article](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/05/16/Disable-Session-affinity-cookie-(ARR-cookie)-for-Azure-web-apps.html) for more details.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this option, but I do not want to fully disable it. I would want that just API requests from Angular no longer pass the Arrafinity cookie.

Comment: What use case do you have that you want it enabled but don't want to use it from Angular, but do from elsewhere?

Comment: I still have old WebForms parts ( telerik), that are stateful .